# Help edit the Wiki Answer: Canonical Book on Agile

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, specific-answer

This post is a call to arms to higher rep users on Programmers that have the ability to view deleted answers.  I merged a couple questions together asking for Agile references on request and took the top voted answer and locked it as a Wiki.  I deleted the rest but there is a bunch of good content still.

[Is there a canonical book on Agile?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-agile/)

Below are links to each of the deleted answers. If you intend on editing it in then edit this question or you feel it is crap then just edit it out of the question.  If you took the last answer then tag this question status completed.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/213382/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/73649/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113253/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/87772/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/83533/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/83515/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/83511/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/83508/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/73153/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/64050/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/27076/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/14086/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/13039/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7953/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7944/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7939/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7908/25476
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7907/25476

Comment: as far as I can tell, only [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/13039), [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7939), [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7908)  and [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7907) are worth considering, the rest would better stay away. Editing them in would be technically easy but I would prefer Thomas Owens to recheck them prior to that, my knowledge of agile books is not good enough

Comment: ...and, while we're at it, how about we drop that stinkin' tag [tag:books] off it (presence of word book in th title would suffice)

Comment: Should we put these into the agile tag wiki (and maybe the other tag wikis, as appropriate - unit-testing, scrum, extreme-programming, etc. etc)? We can even link to the Amazon page for the Stack Exchange referrer, if one exists.

Comment: But yeah. I'll take a closer look. Most of the books referenced do look legit, though.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I haven't yet made up my mind which way is better, but in case if we decide to keep it as collab effort answer, I think we would at least add a reference to it to agile tag wiki

Comment: @gnat In current state, a question is probably better from a user's perspective. But I think that if communities start to use tag wikis, there would be more incentive for Stack Exchange to do something to make them better (better attribution, searchability, linking, etc.). This type of thing is very well-suited to the idea behind tag wikis.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'd be completely happy and in agreement with moving the book lists into the assorted tag wikis. It helps keep the 'but other people asked for recommendations' type questions off the main site while retaining the content in a permanently accessible place that isn't subject to deletion and cleanups and still allow for the community to maintain it.

Comment: It's showing as locked, not community wiki.  The link to http://www.jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/ has been lost in the edits, and I couldn't put it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the following tag pages to include links to the Amazon pages for the books mentioned in the question:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/agile/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/scrum/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/extreme-programming/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/unit-testing/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/continuous-delivery/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/estimation/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/time-estimation/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/project-planning/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/project-management/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/retrospective/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/user-story/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/requirements/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/lean/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/object-oriented-design/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/tdd/info
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/product-management/info

Admittedly, wikis aren't the best place right now. But I think putting this type of information into tag wikis in some form is a good start - if they become more useful to a community, maybe Stack Exchange will beef up the tools around using them.